# How to cancel "/usr/local/nagios/bin/import_runtime -q"?

Tags: centos, nagios

Every hour I get an email from the server with the following cron error:

```
DBI connect('database=runtime;host=localhost','nagios',...) failed:  
 Access denied for user 'nagios'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at
  /usr/local/nagios/perl/lib/Ima/DBI.pm line 329
```

We do not actually use nagios on that server, so it is okay if it is not working.
I would like to stop this cron job but I cannot find the cron file where it is rooted.

`/etc/cron.hourly` does not have it.
`crontab -l` does not show it.

The only place I could find this command was this file:

```
/usr/local/nagios/installer/crontab.nagios
```

I'm not sure if I should manipulate this file however.

Comment: Did you take a look at `/var/spool/cron`?

Comment: @quanta  , I checked it now and there is a file named `nagios`. I can see the relevant line within that file. I've commented it out. Let's see what happens. Would you like to write an answer to this question, so I can mark it in case it resolves the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have a cron job running as `nagios` user. So, take at look at `/var/spool/cron` or use `crontab -l -u nagios` command to check. If it exists and you don't want to use, just comment out or execute `crontab -r -u nagios` to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked /etc/cron.d?

If you do not run Nagios on that host, editing the script is safe - as it would only affect Nagios.

Comment: Yes I've checked /etc/cron.d

Comment: You should check all the files in /etc/cron.d/, you should check /etc/cron.hourly for symlinks, you should check /etc/crontab, and /var/spool/cron ... crontab -l lists /var/spool/cron/-contents for the current user ... it may be the nagios-user.